# How do I round off date to the nearest hour in a JSON file using Python?

Tags: python, json

I want to round off time to the nearest hour in a JSON file which has a collection of tweets with different timestamps. 
Example:

```
{    
    "created_at": "Tue Sep 30 01:24:46 +0000 2018",
```

Here I want to round off the time to 01:00:00. Could anyone help with a script which can do that in python? I tried to use this but since the timestamp changes for every tweet I'm unable to do it.

```
            line = re.sub('^{"created_at": "Tue Sep 30 01:24:46', '^{"created_at": "Tue Sep 30 01:24:46,', line)
```

Any help  is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I'd use re to pull out `xx:xx:xx`, which you could then split into a list, convert to ints, and round as needed. Then sub it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> timestamp = "Tue Sep 30 01:24:46 +0000 2018"

>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> original = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
>>> original
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 30, 1, 24, 46, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> modified = original.replace(minute=0, second=0)
>>> modified
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 30, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> modified.isoformat()
'2018-09-30T01:00:00+00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a python library like [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) to parse dates in general.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer?